# Qgis2Web wfs data doesn't show

Tags: qgis, leaflet, wfs, qgis2web

I've enabled the plugin qgis2web, after getting one WFS layer in to QGIS I started the gis2web plugin. Because it is a WFS layer and I want leaflet to use that WFS I don't check the Encode to JSON option.

The preview shows only the base layer. If I do enable the Encode to JSON option, my layer does show.

I've tried with different WFS-services in QGIS 2.10.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see WFS related code in the resulting Javascript? Might be worth a bug report on https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues

Comment: in the index.html I do see  a line of code with te wfs-links   
    </script>
        <script src='http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/brpgewaspercelen/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=brpgewaspercelen:brpgewaspercelen&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&BBOX=0,300000,300000,600000&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3AgetbrpgewaspercelenJson'></script>

Comment: I have had the same issue. My workaround it to add the WFS in afterwards though I have only done that using OL3 rather than leaflet.

Comment: Can you send me projects which have this problem? I can't recreate it yet. There is a GH issue for it: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/102

Comment: I tried to give some information about the project. I hope can make something out of it otherwise let me know

Answer (score 1):

This could be because I've coded the WFS support to work with JSONP from Geoserver. If your WFS is not Geoserver, it probably won't work. I've also just released 0.36.0 which now supports Geoserver WFS in OL3 exports.